# How to handle IP Address rerouting with .NET Remoting

Tags: c#, .net-remoting

I have a process within a network that wants to talk to a service on another network.  So I have two computers:

```
Client                            Server
172.X.X.X  reroute-> 172.X.X.X to 10.0.1.X
```

With this setup, I can call the Server with the 172.X.X.X ip address and it maps to the 10.0.1.X address and talks fine.  However, when I try to use .NET Remoting and communicate, I get an exception:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.0.1.240:8196

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.RemoteConnection.CreateNewSocket(EndPoint ipEndPoint)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.RemoteConnection.CreateNewSocket()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.RemoteConnection.GetSocket()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketCache.GetSocket(String machinePortAndSid, Boolean openNew)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.SendRequestWithRetry(IMessage msg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.ProcessMessage(IMessage msg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream, ITransportHeaders& responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryClientFormatterSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Aloha.Automation.IBackOfHouseFileServer.get_SecurityKey()
   at Aloha.Automation.Presentation.ViewModel.TerminalViewModel.RefreshSecurityKeyFromTerminal() in c:\BuildAgent\work\78a60abb233492e7\Source\Aloha.Automation.Presentation\ViewModel\TerminalViewModel.cs:line 167
   at Aloha.Automation.Presentation.ViewModel.TerminalViewModel.Refresh() in c:\BuildAgent\work\78a60abb233492e7\Source\Aloha.Automation.Presentation\ViewModel\TerminalViewModel.cs:line 225
   at Aloha.Automation.Presentation.ViewModel.TerminalViewModel.LabConnectorViewModelOnPropertyChanged(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args) in c:\BuildAgent\work\78a60abb233492e7\Source\Aloha.Automation.Presentation\ViewModel\TerminalViewModel.cs:line 154
   at System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at Caliburn.Core.PropertyChangedBase.RaisePropertyChangedEventImmediately(String propertyName) in c:\Code\caliburn\branches\v1.1\src\Caliburn.Core\PropertyChangedBase.cs:line 49
   at Aloha.Automation.Presentation.ViewModel.ExtendedPresenter.<>c__DisplayClass1.<NotifyOfPropertyChange>b__0() in c:\BuildAgent\work\78a60abb233492e7\Source\Aloha.Automation.Presentation\ViewModel\DetailsViewModel.cs:line 42
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)]]>
```

How should I handle this situation?  Do I need to switch remoting technologies or roll my own?

Comment: I would recommend you switch to WCF.

Comment: How are you talking to the server when it "works" ? via http ? Is your gateway set up to port forward everything to the server or just e.g. port 80 ?

Comment: @Jaxidian I'm looking into WCF right now. 

@nos it only works when the ip of the computer matches the ip I use from the client.  If I do rerouting it doesn't work.

Comment: That suggests it's the rerouting not working properly.

Comment: Switching to WCF was what I had to do.  that was the answer, if you want to post it as such and get credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with .NET.  When you're having ip rerouting issues, switch to WCF.